# How to draw a smooth curve between 2 points given the 2 tangents at them?

Tags: interpolation, bezier-curve

Let me ask a question , given 2 points on the XY plane and given the 2 tangents at them, how to compute an arbitrary chosen smooth curve passing the 2 given points. For details, traveling along the curve in one direction, the curvature must satisfy (Condition A or Condition B) given

Condition A. the curvature does not increase ;
 Condition B. the curvature does not decrease.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You've looked up Hermite interpolation?

Comment: @J.M. No. Although I knew the name , cspline, I had no idea of that it was the one I looked for . Thank you very much.

Comment: The special case of curvature changing *linearly* with length along the curve is called an [Euler spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_spiral). You might find some information about fitting Euler spirals to points in [Raph Levien's PhD thesis](http://www.levien.com/phd/phd.html).

Answer (score 2):

Hermite interpolation is the beginning. This will give you a (cubic) curve that matches the two given points and tangents.

But it won't help much with your conditions A and C. To satisfy those, you need to ensure that your curve has "monotone curvature". If you look up that term, you will find lots of references.